# Errors can be caught and handled sometimes then why do most of the blogs claim that they should be handled and all?

Tags: java, error-handling

Why do most of the blogs say that errors cannot be handled? For example in the following code I have done so. Why do most of the blogs claim that errors should not be handled?

```
package errors;

public class StackOverflowErrorDemo {

    public void method1() {
        this.method2();
    }

    public void method2() {
        this.method1();
    }

    public static void main(String sri[]) {
        try {
            StackOverflowErrorDemo k = new StackOverflowErrorDemo();
            k.method1();
        } catch(StackOverflowError error) {
            System.out.println(" Inside catch of stackoverflow");
        }

        System.out.println("  after error has been caught!!");
    }
}
```

Comment: In "real life" catching StackOverflow and OutOfMemory is iffy at best.  Sometimes the catch works, sometimes the JVM chokes before the exception handler can be given control.

Comment: I would have changed the title, but I held off since I'm not 100% sure if you wanted "errors cannot be handled" or "errors should not be handled" (since you're stating both). Otherwise I'd have also changed the title to something like "Why shouldn't I handle errors?"

Answer (score 3):

I was unsure whether to even respond to this given that it is a rather broad, open-ended question that is unlikely to be particularly suitable for SO, but I'll try to limit my response to the code you've posted.

The example you have provided is not really exceptional behavior, for one.  The correct behavior of that program relies on it throwing a StackOverflowError.  It will not behave correctly if this error is not thrown.  The fact that you can detect such an error is not really evidence that all errors can be caught and handled in a sensible manner; rather, it's proof that you can detect that an exception has occurred.  Whether there is a sensible action to take once you detect such an exception such that you can still produce correct output and sensible behavior is going to be entirely application-dependent.

If I understand your claim correctly, the point about "most errors cannot be handled" really means that by the time you reach true "error handling" for truly exceptional behavior, you are unlikely to be able to recover in sensible ways. For example:  if your application is some kind of database-driven application and the database goes away, there is little or no sensible behavior you can provide.  Similarly, if you reach a point where your program invariants have been violated by insufficient input validation upstream, then there's probably not a lot you can do beyond giving up and erroring out.